# What's the name of this property of asynchronous actions. (boost asio related)

Tags: asynchronous, boost-asio

The property could be described like so: **if the action gets cancelled, it's handler is guaranteed to be executed with an error**.

For example, the [boost::asio::deadline_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html) doesn't have this property as described in the [Remarks section of documentation for deadline_timer::cancel function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel/overload1.html). So it is possible that even though one cancels a waiting operation on a timer, its callback gets executed without an error.

On the other hand, the property holds for asio sockets (at least I hope so :) as there are no such remarks in the documentation).

EDIT: A pseudo-code demonstrating the lack of this property in deadline timers:

```
1# User calls timer.async_wait with a handler H which is to be
   executed when the action finishes.
2# Time passes.
3# Timeout has been reached, asio internally inserts the handler H into
   a queue for later execution, but with error code indicating success.
   User is unaware of when this step takes place.
4# User calls cancel on the timer, thus would expect the handler to be
   executed with an error code indicating failure.
5# Asio takes the handler H from the queue and executes it with error
   code indicating success as set in the step #3.
```

It is easy to work around this problem by just setting a boolean flag in step #4 and then check it in step #5, so that is not the issue.

Comment: Please clearify what do you want

Comment: I'm mainly interested in knowing the name of the property, if it has one. It's mostly for documentation purposes for the software I'm writing. I would however give +1 for clarification on whether asio sockets have this property or not.

Comment: *Everything* that is cancellable has this property because the cancellation might happen *after* the callback has begun executing. It cannot be undone at this point.

Comment: @usr, I would disagree, I'm not considering threads in this post, just asynchronous actions (no callbacks are called at the same time but they may be executed in unspecified order). So it is easy to make sure that cancel is always called before the callback has begun execution. Also, as mentioned above, the deadline_timer is one of those classes that doesn't have this property, please have a look at the EDIT.

Comment: There's no name for this. I believe all async ops in asio are like this, such that cancellation might not actually work if it's already completed (but hasn't yet called your handler) when you cancel.

Answer (score 4):

Neither the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) nor the [Networking Library Proposal for TR2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2175.pdf) defines a term for asynchronous operations with a guaranteed error upon cancellation.  However, all asynchronous operations, including [`boost::asio::deadline_timer::async_wait()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/async_wait.html), exhibit this behavior.  Handlers are designed so that they always provide the status of the associated operation.  Without this guarantee, developers would be in an unknown state within handlers when either cancellation or multiple operations occur.

Cancellation only works on operations that have not yet taken place.  I believe the documentation accentuates this only for the timer classes because of the difference in the visibility of the asynchronous operations.  The operations on I/O objects have high visibility.  For example, one could sniff the network to observe an asynchronous write operation on a socket.  On the other hand, the timers' operations have low visibility.  The wait operation's mechanics are an implementation detail within Boost.Asio, and the API does not provide the ability to perform external monitoring of the operation.

In the pseudo-code, the timeout has been reached, indicating the asynchronous wait operation has completed.  As such, it can no longer be cancelled as the action has already taken place.  Therefore, the handler will not be invoked with an error of `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.  It is critical to understand that cancellation is an action, not a state change.  Thus, there is no way to query the timer to see if cancellation had occurred.  Also, if a user expects the cancellation to modify the handler's error code, then the user may be lost in the inherit complexity resulting from the separation in time between the initiation, completion, and notification of asynchronous operations.

---

Everything below is very specific on implementation details.  In this scenario, an asynchronously read is occuring on a socket using [boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_receive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_receive.html) on system where Boost.Asio will use epoll for its reactor.

#### Initialization

1. When the socket object is created, its service, [`reactive_socket_service_base`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/impl/reactive_socket_service_base.ipp) informs the reactor to initialize task (`reactor::init_task()`).
2. The reactor will then inform the `io_service` to initialize for task.  This causes a marker operation to be added to the `io_service`'s operation queue.
3. When the socket opens with a valid file descriptor, a struct of data associated with the file descriptor (`descriptor_data`) is registered with the reactor.  This struct has its own operation queue, and is actually treated as an operation itself.
4. The reactor extracts the file descriptor from `descriptor_data` and adds it to the list of file descriptors to observe within the reactor.

#### Initiation of asynchronous read operation

1. [`boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::async_receive()`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_service_base.hpp) creates an [`boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_recv_op.hpp) object.  This object is an operation object.  Its `perform()` member function will try to read data from the socket, and its `complete()` member function will invoke the user's completion handler.
2. [`boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::start_op()`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/impl/reactive_socket_service_base.ipp) is invoked with the read operation, which invokes the [`reactor::start_op()`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp).
3. The reactor obtains the `descriptor_data` for the socket, locks the descriptor-specific mutex, pushes the operation into the descriptor-specific operation queue, informs `io_service` that there is work, then unlocks the mutex.

#### The socket gets data, and the completion of asynchronous read operation starts

1. `io_service::run*()` is invoked.
2. The `io_service` will only check in its operation queue if any operations are ready to run.  In this case, the marker operation that was created during initialization is in the queue.  The operation is identified as the marker, which indicates a reactor exists, and invokes [`reactor::run()`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp).
3. The reactor will block on `epoll_wait`.  When the socket's file descriptor has activity, then the event is identified.  The `descriptor_data` is extracted from the event, and pushes it into the caller's operation queue, as `descriptor_data` is an operation.
4. The operations passed back to the caller are then added to the `io_service`'s operation queue, which now contains the `descriptor_data` operation and the original marker operation.
5. The `descriptor_data` operation is popped from the `io_service` queue, and invokes the `complete()` member function, causing [`epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::do_complete`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp) to run.
6. `do_complete` invokes `epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::perform_io`, where in the operations in the `descriptor_data`'s operation queue are iterated over and `perform()` is invoked.  This includes the `boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op` operation that was pushed into the queue during the initiation of the asynchronous operation.
7. The read operation's `perform()` member function will invoke [`socket_ops::non_blocking_recv()`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp), where the actual data is attempted to be read from the socket.  The error code and bytes transferred are stored in the operation.
8. The operation is removed from the `descriptor_data`'s operation queue, and added to the `io_service` via [`task_io_service::post_deferred_completion`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp).

#### Notification of the asynchronous read operation

1. The `io_service` now has two operations in its queue: the completed read operation and the marker operation.  The `reactor` has no operations in its queue.
2. The read operation is eventually iterated to, and its `complete()` member function invokes.  Within [`reactive_socket_recv_op::do_complete`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_recv_op.hpp), the user handler invokes with the error code and bytes transferred.

#### Cancellation

1. [`boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::cancel()`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/impl/reactive_socket_service_base.ipp) invokes `reactor::cancel_ops` with `descriptor_data`.
2. [`epoll_reactor::cancel_ops()`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp) iterates over the `descriptor_data`'s operation queue.  Each operation is popped from the `descriptor_data`'s operation queue, has its error code set to `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`, then added to the `io_service`'s operation queue.

Thus, cancellation only affects operations that have not yet been invoked by removing them from the `descriptor_data`'s operation queue.  If an operation has been invoked, then it has already been removed from the `descriptor_data`'s operation queue and added to the `io_service` operation queue.

Comment: Wow, it will take me some time to understand those steps. I'm a bit confused with the rest though, in the first paragraph you write that *all asynchronous operations exhibit this behavior* (I take it that means the property in question), but in the last paragraph you write that *cancellation only affects operations that have not yet been invoked* (thus it is not guaranteed that the handler will be called with an error if the operation had been cancelled). I find these two claims contradictory. I think we are miss understanding each other at something, just don't know what it is.

Comment: @PeterJankuliak I think the misunderstanding is the result of coupling the completion of an operation and notification of the completion. If you invoke `async_write` (initiation), data is written to the socket (completion), how you intend to prevent (cancel) the receiver from getting the bytes?  Maybe you can elaborate in the original post why you believe a user expects the handler to be executed with error in step #4 of the pseudo-code?  As a user, I would only expect the action (waiting) to have its handler called with an error if the action was cancelled (wait forced to stop prematurely).