# async_read_some to emulate syncronous timeout receive

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

My program always used the platform-dependent synchronous receive, which blocked the execution until timeout or receive event, something like:

`recv(buf, size, timeout);`

Now I want to replace this code with boost to make it cross-platform. I found the solution, but it is quite ugly I think (in comparison with single function call). I wrote this:

```
void IPV4_HOST::recv_timer_handler(const boost::system::error_code & e)
{
    if (e.value() == boost::system::errc::success) {
        f_recv_timeout = true;
        asio_socket.cancel();
    }
}

void IPV4_HOST::recv_handler(const boost::system::error_code & , size_t bytes)
{
    recv_timer.cancel();
    bytes_received = bytes;
}

int IPV4_HOST::receive(void * buf, size_t buf_size, TIME::INTERVAL timeout)
{
    f_recv_timeout = false;
    bytes_received = 0;

    recv_timer.expires_from_now(timeout.get_boost_milli());
    recv_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&IPV4_HOST::recv_timer_handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    asio_socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf, buf_size),
                                boost::bind(&IPV4_HOST::recv_handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    io_service.run();

    if (f_recv_timeout)
        throw IO::TimeoutReceiveException();

    return bytes_received;
}
```

Could you please advise, am I doing it right or not? Is there simpler way to do this?

Comment: See the following answer by the library author: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/asio-setting-a-timeout-on-blocking-write-s-read-s-tt2624802.html#a2624803

Comment: This is almost equal to what i did, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is in the right direction, but there are some subtle points to consider:

- If any other work is posted into `io_service`, then `IPV4_HOST::receive()` will start processing that work.
- When [`io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) returns under normal conditions, it is implied that the `io_service` has been stopped.  Subsequent calls to `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or, `poll_one()` will return immediately unless the io_service is [`reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html).
- It is possible for both asynchronous operations to complete at the same time, making both completion handlers ready to run with success.  This behavior is accentuated in the remarks section of [`deadline_timer::cancel()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel/overload1.html); however, all asynchronous operations exhibit this [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14116082/1053968).  In the existing code, this can result in `IO::TimeoutReceiveException` being thrown when `bytes_received` is greater than zero.

One solution to handle the `io_service` details, as well as the non-deterministic order of execution with the completion handlers, may look something like:

```
void IPV4_HOST::recv_timer_handler(const boost::system::error_code & e)
{
  timer_handled = true;
  if (!e) {
    f_recv_timeout = true;
    asio_socket.cancel();
  }
}

void IPV4_HOST::recv_handler(const boost::system::error_code &,
                             size_t bytes)
{
  recv_handled = true;
  recv_timer.cancel();
  bytes_received = bytes;
}

int IPV4_HOST::receive(void * buf, size_t buf_size, TIME::INTERVAL timeout)
{
  timer_handled  = false;
  recv_handled   = false;
  f_recv_timeout = false;
  bytes_received = 0;

  recv_timer.expires_from_now(timeout.get_boost_milli());
  recv_timer.async_wait(
    boost::bind(&IPV4_HOST::recv_timer_handler, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));

  asio_socket.async_read_some(
    boost::asio::buffer(buf, buf_size),
    boost::bind(&IPV4_HOST::recv_handler, this, 
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

  // If a handler has not ran, then keep processing work on the io_service.
  // We need to consume both handlers so that old handlers are not in the
  // io_service the next time receive is called.
  while (!timer_handled || !recv_handled)
  {
    io_service.run_one();
  }

  // If the io_service has stopped (due to running out of work), then reset
  // it so that it can be run on next call to receive.
  if (io_service.stopped())
    io_service.reset();

  // If no bytes were received and the timeout occurred, then throw.  This
  // handles the case where both a timeout and receive occurred at the 
  // same time.
  if (!bytes_received && f_recv_timeout)
    throw IO::TimeoutReceiveException();

  return bytes_received;
}
```

Also, as you are trying to obtain cross-platform behavior, read the remarks of [`basic_stream_socket::cancel()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload1.html).  There are some platform specific behaviors of which to be aware.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, I tested code with your corrections and now it works really stable. The only thing I did not get is why should we check io_service.stopped() before doing reset? Why cannot we just call reset every time? Is it for case if we use io_service somewhere else for other handlers?

Comment: Correct.  `reset()` cannot safely be called if there are any unfinished calls to the `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()`, or `poll_one()` functions.  I was unsure as to whether or not `io_service` was being used for other handlers, so opted for the safer solution.